# JQuery Cookie issue with order cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I want to save table row order using JQuery cookie.

But my code don't working.

Can you help me? Thanks in advance!

**HTML:**

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th class="text-center">Name</th>
          <th class="text-center">Surname</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td>Chris</td>
          <td>A</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button id="save" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">save</button>
```

**script.js**

```
$('tbody').sortable({
    axis: 'y',
}).disableSelection();

var savedOrd = $.cookie('sortOrder');
if (savedOrd) {
    $.each(savedOrd.split(','), function (i, e) {
        $('#' + e).insertAfter('tbody>td:eq(' + i + ')');
    });
};
$('#save').click(function () {
    var saveOrd = $('tbody').sortable('toArray');
    $.cookie('sortOrder', saveOrd);
});
```

Selectable working. Save button with cookie not.

Comment: `sortable('toArray')` return an array of item ids which is ids of those `<tr>` from your html. There's no id set to those tr then cookie `sortOrder` is null. Besides, you're wrong in the way you use that cookie data

Comment: So can you help me with solution my problem? What is best way to save order list using cookie.